# Install WordPress MU outside htdocs

Tags: multisite, virtual-hosts

I would like to use WP's MU function to host multiple blogs on the same hosting. I intend to use the Domain Mapping plugin to make it work with different vhosts.

My hosting structure is as follows :

```
web
    includes
    vhosts
        domain
            htdocs
```

I would like it so that my Wordpress install is in the includes directory with my other CMS libraries. Is this possible knowing that I have access to httpd.conf and php.ini.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WordPress expects certain directory structure. Now, there are some constants available that you could change in you `wp-config.php` and it should work, in theory anyway. The thing is that many plugins expect the default directory structure (and names) and will break if you change this. I have never tried to do what you propose, my limit has been renaming the `wp-content` directory.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder and below

I can think of one situation why you would like to do this: to have a single code to update. In that case it might be worth to take a look at Network feature: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network